# Idiom for detecting sequence of rising/falling edges in systemverilog

Tags: system-verilog, verification

I'm writing verification code in system verilog. For reasons beyond the scope of this question, I need to check if, within the high-period of the next clock cycle (i.e., between the next rising and falling edge), a signal pulses up and down exactly once.

While this can be easily done with a state machine, since this does not need to be synthesizeable, I'm hoping to take advantage of SV constructs to make the intent of the code more salient.

I've considered using an event based solution:

```
event re_clk, fe_clk, re_sig, fe_sig;

fork
    forever begin @(pos_edge clk)
        -> re_clk; end
    forever begin @(neg_edge clk)
        -> fe_clk; end
    forever begin @(pos_edge sig)
        -> re_sigl end
    forever begin @(neg_edge sig)
        -> fe_sig; end
    begin 
        wait_order(re_clk, re_sig, fe_sig, fe_clk);
            //Set some signals.
        else
            //Set other signals.
    end
join_any
disable fork;
```

This solution is incredibly verbose. Is there a more idiomatic approach?

Answer (score 2):

You could do the following, which looks more succinct to me:

```
bit good_pulse = 0;
fork
  @(posedge clk) @(negedge clk);
  begin
    @(posedge sig) @(negedge sig) good_pulse = 1;
    @(posedge sig) good_pulse = 0;
  end
join_any
disable fork;
if (good_pulse)
   //Set some signals.
        else
   //Set other signals.
```